# Первый раз встречающиеся по дате

Tags: mysql

Есть табличка состоящая из колонок id, date, status.
id повторяются. Мне нужно отобрать всю строку, где id впервые появляются во всей таблице согласно дате.

Comment: Выберите в подзапросе минимальную дату для каждого ID, и используйте полученные пары для отбора записей.

Comment: спасибо большое. как раз так и сделал